# Access State in Store From Routing Setup File [react-router v4 + redux-thunk]

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, redux-thunk

I'm currently developing a ReactJS Web app (*newbie*). I'm using react-router v4 and redux-thunk.

I would like to know how can I access the current value of the state from my store in my `routes.js` file. The value returned from the store is "true" or "false". I want to access that value of the state in order to verify the "auth_status === true" condition in my constant `PrivateRoute` in my `routes.js` file.

In short, an action named `verifyAuth` from my `authActions.js` file is dispatched from my `Login.js` file. The payload is set to "true" or "false" from there. I want to retrieve `isAuthenticated` from my `authReducer.js` file.

A sample from my files `index.js` (main), `routes.js`, `index.js` (reducers), and `authReducer.js`:

`index.js` (main) file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Routes from './main/routes';
import store from './main/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Routes/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`routes.js` file:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Login from './login';
    import App from './App';
    import MainHome from '../pages/home/home';

    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => (
      <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        **auth_status === true**
        ? <Layout>
            <Component {...props}/>
          </Layout>
        : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/'
        }}/>
      )}/>
    );

    const Routes = () => (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/home" layout={App} component={MainHome}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );

export default Routes;
```

`index.js` (reducers) file:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer
});
```

`authReducer.js` file:

```
import { VERIFY_AUTH } from '../actions/actionsType';

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case VERIFY_AUTH: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: action.payload }
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to connect your component to the Redux Store. First of all import the connect method:

```
 import connect from "react-redux"
```

Then connect you PrivateRoute to the Store using the connect method.

```
PrivateRoute = connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute )
```

Then create the mapStateToProps method. It will "map" the state to get the props you need.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth_status : state.auth.isAuthenticated
  }
}
```

From now on, your component PrivateRoute will have access to the prop "auth_status" that have the value of your "isAuthenticated" on your auth property on your store.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It is not working: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth_status' of undefined"

Comment: Hi Julia, take a look at this codesandbox.io with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q768v52vr6

Comment: Hi Silvio, thank you. It is partially working: I don't know why but there are some bugs with my side menu with these configurations for the private route. It is not working properly but without the private route configurations it works as expected.

Comment: Hi Julia, if you could provide with a snippet of your code, or ideally, a snippet where the problems occurs, I may be of bigger help.

Comment: Hi Silvio, I explained my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498568/privateroute-not-working-properly-bugs-with-my-side-menu-react-router-v4