# Bugs in Sidebar Menu with React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, react-router-dom

I'm developing a single-page ReactJS Web app but I know I'm doing something wrong while defining my routing with `React Router V4`.

My problem is as follows: `PrivateRoute` in my `routes.js` file is not working as expected. That is, I don't know why but my sidebar menu, which is a child component of my main `App`, does not work properly: there are a few bugs when I click on the menu item of my `PrivateRoute` component (in this case, `Page1`). When I say bugs, I mean that when I click on the menu item of a `PrivateRoute`, the sidebar menu is misconfigured. The content of the component (`Page1`) is rendered but the menu item in the sidebar menu does not stay highlighted as it should be: it is redirected to the first menu item on the list, in this case `MainHome`.

Nonetheless, if I change the tag of my `Page1` component from `PrivateRoute` to `ConfigRoute` in my `routes.js` file, everything works properly.

A sample from my files `index.js` (main), `routes.js`, `App.js`, and `side-menu.js`:

`index.js` (main) file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Routes from './routes';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Routes/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`routes.js` file:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Login from './login';
import App from './App';
import MainHome from './home';
import Page1 from './page1';

const ConfigRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...props}/>
    </Layout>
  )}/>
);

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, auth_status, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    <Fragment>
      {auth_status === true
        ? (
          <Layout>
            <Component {...props}/>
          </Layout>
          )
        : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }}/>
          )
      }
    </Fragment>
  )}/>
);

const Routes = (props) => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
      <ConfigRoute path="/home" layout={App} component={MainHome}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/page1" auth_status={props.auth_status} layout={App} component={Page1}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

const mapStatetoProps = state => ({
  auth_status: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(Routes);
```

`App.js` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'antd';
import SideMenu from './side-menu';
import MainHeader from './main-header';
import MainFooter from './main-footer';

const { Content } = Layout;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: false,
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
        <SideMenu collapsed={this.state.collapsed}/>
        <Layout>
          <MainHeader triggerParentUpdate={this.toggle} collapsed={this.state.collapsed}/>
          <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px', padding: 24, background: '#ffffff', minHeight: 280 }}>
            {this.props.children}
          </Content>
          <MainFooter/>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`side-menu.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const { Sider } = Layout;
const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;

class SideMenu extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Sider
        trigger={null}
        collapsible
        collapsed={this.props.collapsed}
        >
          <div className="logo"/>
          <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
            <Menu.Item key="1">
              <NavLink to="/home">
                <Icon type="home"/>
                <span>home</span>
              </NavLink>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">
              <NavLink to="/page1">
                <Icon type="star-o"/>
                <span>page 1</span>
              </NavLink>
            </Menu.Item>       
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
    );
  }
}

export default SideMenu;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found one possible solution [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/6576#issuecomment-398355506) - use the path as the menu keys and provide the location as the `selectedKeys`:

```
<Menu mode="inline" selectedKeys={[location.pathname]}>
  <Menu.Item key="/home">
    <Link to="/home">Home </Link>
  </Menu.Item>
...
```

You can test the solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/84o15l7nvj?module=%2Fsrc%2FsideMenu.js)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay, understood! Thank you :) Nonetheless, I have a problem with the menu if I add a SubMenu inside it: it collapses when it shouldn't. I edited the codesandbox code. Click on home then page 2 (subnav). Do you have a solution?